# SQL Calculate Daily Profit From Given Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently trying to calculate the daily profit for each account since 14th August.

I have the following SQL which works fine for getting the profit (calculated by getting the first login per account yesterday and the first login per account today) for the last day but how do I take it further to get the daily profit for each account since 14/08?

```
SELECT A.accountName, B.date AS Date, (A.total - B.total) AS Profit 
FROM
    (SELECT accountName, CAST(logInTime AS DATE) AS date, total
     FROM LoginLog
     WHERE logID IN (SELECT MIN(logID) 
                     FROM LoginLog 
                     WHERE logInTime > CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
                     GROUP BY accountName, CAST(logInTime AS DATE)
                     )
     ) A
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT accountName, CAST(logInTime AS DATE) AS date, total
     FROM LoginLog
     WHERE logID IN (SELECT MIN(logID) 
                     FROM LoginLog 
                     WHERE logInTime > CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()) AS DATE) 
                       AND logInTime < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
                     GROUP BY accountName, CAST(logInTime AS DATE) 
                     )
      ) B
ON A.accountName = B.accountName
ORDER BY accountName
```

An example of the records in the LoginLog table are as follows:

```
accountName           logInTime                   total
--------------------- --------------------------- -----------
AddableDeer621        2014-08-21 09:26:58.000     14131
StewyClown7           2014-08-21 09:20:17.000     37550
StewyClown7           2014-08-21 09:04:26.000     37550
AddableDeer621        2014-08-20 16:36:13.000     11864
StewyClown7           2014-08-20 16:34:03.000     37550
StewyClown7           2014-08-20 16:29:40.000     37550
AddableDeer621        2014-08-20 15:18:51.000     10038
StewyClown7           2014-08-20 15:12:10.000     33750
AddableDeer621        2014-08-20 14:44:41.000     9077
StewyClown7           2014-08-20 14:38:00.000     33750
AddableDeer621        2014-08-20 14:10:48.000     9077
StewyClown7           2014-08-20 14:03:55.000     33750
AddableDeer621        2014-08-20 12:53:15.000     9077
StewyClown7           2014-08-20 12:46:36.000     33750
AddableDeer621        2014-08-20 11:58:59.000     9077
AddableDeer621        2014-08-20 05:13:24.000     9077
AddableDeer621        2014-08-20 03:25:01.000     8827
AddableDeer621        2014-08-20 02:16:04.000     7622
AddableDeer621        2014-08-20 00:00:02.000     7622
AddableDeer621        2014-08-19 22:48:57.000     7622
AddableDeer621        2014-08-19 21:39:45.000     5777
AddableDeer621        2014-08-19 20:30:45.000     5777
AddableDeer621        2014-08-19 19:22:03.000     4912
```

And an example of what I'd like the results to show as is as follows:

```
accountName           Date           Profit
--------------------- -------------- -----------
AddableDeer621        2014-08-20     6509
StewyClown7           2014-08-20     4000
AddableDeer621        2014-08-19     2710
```

If you need any more info then let me know

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.accountName, B.date AS Date, (A.total - B.total) AS Profit 
FROM
(SELECT accountName, CAST(logInTime AS DATE) AS date, total
 FROM LoginLog
 WHERE logID IN (SELECT MIN(logID) 
                 FROM LoginLog 
                 WHERE logInTime > '2014-08-14 00:00:00.000'
                 GROUP BY accountName, CAST(logInTime AS DATE)
                 )
 ) A
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT accountName, CAST(logInTime AS DATE) AS date, total
 FROM LoginLog
 WHERE logID IN (SELECT MIN(logID) 
                 FROM LoginLog 
                 WHERE logInTime > CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()) AS DATE) 
                   AND logInTime < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
                 GROUP BY accountName, CAST(logInTime AS DATE) 
                 )
  ) B
ON A.accountName = B.accountName
ORDER BY accountName
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even sure what your question is (sample data and desired results would *really* help).  But you can greatly simplify your existing query.  You can identify the first record on each day using `row_number()` and then use conditional aggregation to get the results you want:

```
select ll.accountName, 
       max(case when IsToday = 0 then ll.logindate end) as date,
       sum(case when IsToday = 1 then ll.total else -ll.total end) as profit
from (select ll.*,
             (case when cast(logInTime as date) = cast(getdate() as date) then 1 else 0
              end) as IsToday,
             cast(logintime as date) as logindate,
             row_number() over (partition by accountname, cast(logintime as date order by logid) as seqnum
      from loginlog ll
      where logInTime > CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
order by ll.accountName;
```

This query is more easily generalized to additional days.

Comment: So what I'm looking to try and achieve is for account 1 what was the profit on the 14th, 15th, 16th etc. This will be calculated by taking the total from the first login on the 15th minus the total from the first login on the 14th, etc. I'll update my question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

**Second attempt**:

```
WITH FirstLogin_CTE
AS (
    -- Get the first login for all days
    SELECT accountName, CAST(logInTime AS DATE) AS date, MIN(logID) MinLogId
    FROM LoginLog
    WHERE logInTime >= '2014-08-14'
    GROUP BY accountName, CAST(logInTime AS DATE)
)

SELECT X.accountName, X.PreviousDate As Date, (A.total - B.total) AS Profit 
FROM (
    SELECT cte.accountName, cte.date As CurrentDate, cte.MinLogId as CurrentId, prev.date As PreviousDate, prev.MinLogId as PreviousId
    FROM FirstLogin_CTE cte
    LEFT JOIN FirstLogin_CTE prev ON prev.accountName = cte.accountName AND prev.date = DateAdd(day, -1, cte.date)
) X
INNER JOIN LoginLog A
    ON A.accountName = X.accountName AND A.logID = X.CurrentId
INNER JOIN LoginLog B
    ON B.accountName = X.accountName AND B.logID = X.PreviousId
```